# Changing Button's Key Event Behavior

Tags: winapi, mfc, win32gui

I'm trying to change the button click key behavior. In Windows standard behavior is that a button having the keyboard focus is being triggered by the space key.

I have my own MFC class derived from CButton and tried it by overriding OnChar and OnKeyUp, but even if I retain the event and don't pass it to CButton, it reacts on space key.

I assume it's not an MFC problem but a general problem to influence this standard behavior. And I'm afraid I cannot solve it while relying on the standard BUTTON class.

Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: Handle [WM_GETDLGCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) and return `DLGC_WANTCHARS` for your button. Make sure to actually handle the SPACE key on your button, otherwise you'll hear the "unhandled keyboard input" message biiing. Raymond Chen has several entries on this message, e.g. [Other tricks with WM_GETDLGCODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031126-00/?p=41703).

Comment: @IInspectable I struggled a bit with the WM_GETDLGCODE, but it looks like I can get along with it. Notes on that: The MFC standard handler OnGetDlgCode() has no parameters, so I cannot know which key was pressed - this can be solved by using ON_MESSAGE and implementing it by myself. Second: I need to overwrite OnKeyDown(), not OnChar(). Thank you!

Comment: Or just use PreTranslateMessage

Comment: `PreTranslateMessage` is the wrong tool. It's a way to side-step the dialog manager, and interferes with it in non-trivial ways. The result is frequently a dialog, that mostly works, but fails in subtle, hard to test ways. [Those who do not understand the dialog manager are doomed to reimplement it, badly](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070627-00/?p=26243) is a good read. It's unfortunate that there is a need for articles like this one. There wouldn't be if Microsoft were brave enough to publish official documentation for something as commonly used as the dialog manager.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, which are both working to prevent the space key triggering my button. But on one step beyond this I want to define another key triggering the button press as normally space does. This works really fine by replacing the key code in wParam of PreTranslateMessage. I realize that TAB handling or such stuff is too complex to reimplement it on my own, but replacing or retaining a key should be quite ok to be done withing PreTranslateMessage.